# Iterating through data structure

Tags: actionscript-3, recursion, tree

I'm kinda wracking my brain on how to iterate through my data object. I've created a recursive function to iterate through XML elements and essentially output the same structure as an object, using the attribute in the element as the key, which holds it's own object. The object, conceptually, looks something like this. It's sort of a Tree, but I'm not using flex Trees, just as3.

[image]

The thing I want to get across is that each "branch" has any number of children, so I can't hard code the depth of each branch.

### What I'm trying to accomplish

Each node in my data structure is a folder name, and I need to append all of the children into a single string and store that. To generate an "asset", i need a string from each of these initial nodes (in the example picture, they'd be 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, and 17). So, I need to iterate through each branch and return a different set than previously, such that every possible asset combination is found.

Conceptually, I know that I need to grab the "1st index" of each branch, output all of those strings into an asset, and then move the first branch up an "index" until it reaches it's limit, which triggers the next branch to move its "index". But, how I actually do that is a bit of a mystery to me.

Do I need to restructure my data tree into an array that can be referenced by index, or is there some simpler way of iterating through every possible combination that I am missing.

I'm using actionscript 3, but I'm not specifically looking for a code example, just pseudo-code is fine.

Comment: Your question is a little vague.  Is the "asset" an image you're trying to load, whose path is a conjunction of string values found at each node?  Are each of these nodes references to assets that you want to simply compile into a single array of strings?  I think what you're asking for is fine, but I need something a bit more concrete.

Comment: asset is a collection of file path strings to an image, 6 images to be exact. Each initial branch from the root is a folder name, and each of it's children are folder names, and so on. So, for instance, the first asset I combine will have file paths ["1/7/9", "2/13", "4/17/19", "5/23", "6/24/26", "17/30"]. The next one will be ["1/7/10", "2/13", "4/17/19", "5/23", "6/24/26", "17/30"]. Does that help clear it up?

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, that's very clear.  Give me a bit to write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're trying to pull out the N'th of every tree into a seperate array of strings, it'll be easier to first distill these trees into their sequential sets (with their concatenations) in a first pass.  A second pass then constructs your intended "asset" arrays.  Because the nature of your document may vary wildly, I've created a demonstration data source below.  You can run the following code, and it will produce the following results:

[image: An Array of arrays of concatenated strings]

```
//Assume the following structure.
var data:Array = [
    {
        "path":"one",
        "sub":[
            {
                "path":"seven",
                "sub":[
                    {"path":"nine.png"},
                    {"path":"ten.png"}
                ]
            },
            {
                "path":"eight",
                "sub":[
                    {"path":"eleven.png"},
                    {"path":"twelve.png"}
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "path":"two",
        "sub":[
            {"path":"thirteen.png"},
            {"path":"fourteen.png"},
            {"path":"fifteen.png"},
            {"path":"sixteen.png"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "path":"four",
        "sub":[
            {
                "path":"seventeen",
                "sub":[
                    {"path":"nineteen.png"},
                    {"path":"twenty.png"}
                ]
            },
            {
                "path":"twenty-two",
                "sub":[
                    {"path":"twenty-one.png"},
                    {"path":"twenty-two.png"}
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "path":"five",
        "sub":[
            {"path":"twenty-three.png"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "path":"six",
        "sub":[
            {
                "path":"twenty-four",
                "sub":[
                    {"path":"twenty-six.png"},
                    {"path":"twenty-seven.png"}
                ]
            },
            {
                "path":"twenty-nine",
                "sub":[
                    {"path":"twenty-eight.png"},
                    {"path":"twenty-nine.png"}
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "path":"seventeen",
        "sub":[
            {"path":"thirtee.png"}
        ]
    }
]

function init():void {
    var sets:Array = [];

    // First we'll create a complete sequence of concatenated strings per set
    for (var i:int = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        sets[i] = [];
        scan(data[i], sets[i]);
    }

    // Find the max length
    var max:int = 0, a:Array;
    for each (a in sets) {
        max = (a.length > max) ? a.length : max;
    }

    // Now we'll create our ordered assets, pulling out the firsts, then the seconds, and so on...
    var assets:Array = [];
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        assets[i] = [];

        for each (a in sets) {
            if (i < a.length) {
                assets[i].push(a[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

function scan(node:Object, a:Array, prefix:String = ""):void {
    var subNode:Object;
    // This is a recursive function which digs till it finds no more sub properties.
    if (node.hasOwnProperty("sub")) {
        // On every sub node, it passes the currently concatenated path so far
        for each (subNode in node.sub) {
            scan(subNode, a, prefix + "/" + node.path);
        }
    } else {
        // When we reach the final depth, we can begin populating our array with paths.
        a.push(prefix + "/" + node.path);
    }
}

init();
```

Comment: It's hard to tell since I can't see the entirety of your results, but it looks like every path is getting a new leaf at the bottom, and I only want that to happen if their parent's left neighbor has looped (or if its null i think). So, essentially, we only want a new leaf from path "two" when path "one" has completely looped back around with all of it's leafs, and we only want "four" to the same when "two" has also looped back around. that way we get every possible combination. Again, I can't see the entirety of your data, so i'm not sure if it actually needs adjusting.

Comment: I will see about getting a better image to describe my issue

Comment: So here's some images that might help. The green lines represent the "path" to the leafs. There are 5 images to represent the first 5 loops, and every loop after that should make sense.
http://imgur.com/a/vCTy3

Comment: i think im on the right path at the moment, ive got a Node class that is assisting in all the things I need to do. I wouldnt put too much effort into this answer

Comment: Aha!  This is quite different than what I thought you were asking then.  By the way, you can see the entire code by scrolling the inline frame (Copy/paste into your own editor, and compile will produce those results in the snapshot).

What you're asking for is to create arrays of every possible combination, or arrays of a pack leader changing position inside the trees end-points?  If it's the latter, then when you enter node 2, and start running  from 13 to 14, node 1's "path" never shifts, correct?

Comment: It sort of works like a clock. Second hand goes up 60 indices before the minute hand goes up 1 index. Minute hand goes up 60 indices before the hour moves one index. Branch 1 can be thought of as the second hand, 2 as the minute, 4 as the hour, and so on. That way, we can cycle through every possible outcome. So after 1 loops once, it triggers 2 to grab the next leaf. Then 1 loops again, and 2 grabs the next leaf. Once 2 loops (grabbing leaf 16 and going back to 13), then branch 4 will grab the next leaf (20). Does that make sense?

Comment: I think i've figured out the answer I had for this specific question. I appreciate the help though, it was integral to me figuring out exactly what I needed though. Problems still persist, but in different areas that this question wasnt meant to answer. Thanks for the help though!